# Identify equality in columns while ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, equals, similarity

How can I ignore the empty/NaN columns with equals of pandas.

So that it returns TRUE is col 2 is the same as 1 and also when col 2 contains a `NaN`

```
df['col1'].equals(df['col2'])
```

Comment: Please share a sample of both dataframes with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with boolean filtering (Symmetric for NA/nan in both columns):

```py
mask = df['col1'].notna() & df['col2'].notna()
df.loc[mask, 'col1'].equals(df.loc[mask, 'col2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediary column (series) identical to col2, but where you set the NaN values to those in col1.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1., 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [1, 2, None, 4, 5, None]})
df['col1'].equals(df['col2'])
s = df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'])
df['col1'].equals(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go on a little deep dive, because some answers won't work if you don't know in which of the columns you encounter missing values. Also let's take a look which answer is the fastest.

So lets create some test data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser1 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10_000)) # Generate random column
ser2 = ser1.copy(deep=True)              # Exact copy of values
ser3 = ser1.copy(deep=True)              # Exact copy of values
ser4 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10_000)) # Different data

# Create independent nans
# ser1 without nans
ser2[np.random.rand(10_000) > 0.8] = np.nan 
ser3[np.random.rand(10_000) > 0.8] = np.nan
ser4[np.random.rand(10_000) > 0.8] = np.nan
```

Current answers as functions that take `pd.Series` (the column type):

```py
# As a sanity check `Series.equals` that is not true for any_value == np.nan
def equality_pandas(a, b):
    return a.equals(b)

def equality_filling_one_sided(a, b):
    return a.equals(b.fillna(a))

def equality_filling_dummy_data(a, b):
    return a.fillna(-9999).equals(b.fillna(a).fillna(-9999))

def equality_boolean_mask(a, b):
    mask = a.notna() & b.notna()
    return a[mask].equals(b[mask])

def equality_pure_boolean(a, b):
    # using binary or operator to make it True if isna
    return ((a == b) | a.isna() | b.isna()).all()
```

Let's define a few tests we would expect from a general comparison function that ignores NaNs and doesn't care about whether you have those NaNs in the left or in the right column

```py
def tests(equal):
    assert equal(ser1, ser1), "Identity has to be true without nan"
    assert equal(ser2, ser2), "Identity with nans at the same position"
    assert equal(ser1, ser2), "Same data, NaNs only on the right"
    assert equal(ser2, ser1), "Same data, NaNs only on the left"
    assert equal(ser2, ser3), "Same data but different NaNs"
    assert not equal(ser1, ser4), "Different data has to be not equal (NaNs only right)"
    assert not equal(ser2, ser4), "Different data has to be not equal (NaNs in both)"
    print("PASS")
```

Running those tests shows that filling only in one direction won't make it commutative (even using a dummy value which generally could be a bad practice). Note that `Series.equals` contrary to the rule that `np.nan == np.nan` is `False` returns `True` if the NaNs are in the exact same place!

```py
>>> tests(equality_pandas)

          2     assert equal(ser1, ser1), "Identity has to be true without nan"
          3     assert equal(ser2, ser2), "Identity with nans at the same position"
    ----> 4     assert equal(ser1, ser2), "Same data, NaNs only on the right"
          5     assert equal(ser2, ser1), "Same data, NaNs only on the left"
          6     assert equal(ser2, ser3), "Same data but different NaNs"


    AssertionError: Same data, NaNs only on the right


>>> tests(equality_filling_one_sided)

          3     assert equal(ser2, ser2), "Identity with nans at the same position"
          4     assert equal(ser1, ser2), "Same data, NaNs only on the right"
    ----> 5     assert equal(ser2, ser1), "Same data, NaNs only on the left"
          6     assert equal(ser2, ser3), "Same data but different NaNs"
          7     assert not equal(ser1, ser4), "Different data has to be not equal"


    AssertionError: Same data, NaNs only on the left


>>> tests(equality_filling_dummy_data)


          3     assert equal(ser2, ser2), "Identity with nans at the same position"
          4     assert equal(ser1, ser2), "Same data, NaNs only on the right"
    ----> 5     assert equal(ser2, ser1), "Same data, NaNs only on the left"
          6     assert equal(ser2, ser3), "Same data but different NaNs"
          7     assert not equal(ser1, ser4), "Different data has to be not equal"


    AssertionError: Same data, NaNs only on the left


>>> tests(equality_boolean_mask)
PASS

>>> tests(equality_pure_boolean)
PASS
```

### Performance

Now let's quickly see which method returns an answer the fastest

```py
%%timeit
equality_filling_one_sided(ser1, ser2)

    910 µs ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%%timeit
equality_filling_dummy_data(ser1, ser2)

    1.27 ms ± 67.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%%timeit
equality_boolean_mask(ser1, ser2)

    2.15 ms ± 94.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit
equality_pure_boolean(ser1, ser2)

    1.34 ms ± 32.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

As you can see the boolean solutions require more intermediate results to be computed separately and are thus slower, despite being closer to what you would write if you wrote it as optimized C code.

If you know you only have NaNs in the right column/Series you can use the `equality_filling_one_sided` solution for the best performance;

### Ideal commutative solution

So if we want commutative comparison ignoring NaNs both on the left and the right the fastest way is to use:

```py
def equality_filling_two_sided(a, b):
    f_a = a.fillna(b)
    f_b = b.fillna(a)
    return f_a.equals(f_b)
```

```
>>> tests(equality_filling_two_sided)
PASS


%%timeit
equality_filling_two_sided(ser1, ser2)

    962 µs ± 35.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Which is neglibly slower than the one-sided solution, but fulfills all requirements